# How to select what html would be hidden if dropdownlist selected without js?

Tags: html

I got this page as far as it is now.
And i need to hide some html if the dropdownlist selected another value.
And when i select something else of the dropdown the first value needs to be hidden.

Here is my code:

```
<h1>Geschaafd hout </h1> 
<p>vurenhout geschaafd met 4 ronde hoeken c 18 kwaliteit noord europees.</p> 
<select> 
  <option value="Geschaafd 46x196">Geschaafd 46x196</option> 
  <option value="Geschaafd 46x146">Geschaafd 46x146</option> 
  <option value="Geschaafd 46x96">Geschaafd 46x96</option> 
  <option value="Geschaafd 46x71">Geschaafd 46x71</option> 
  <option value="Geschaafd 46x71">Geschaafd 46x46</option> 
</select> 
<div><span style="line-height: normal; white-space: pre;"><br />
     </span> 
  <table style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;"> 
    <tbody> 
      <tr> 
        <td style="font-weight: bold;">Artikel nr</td> 
        <td style="font-weight: bold;">Omschrijving</td> 
        <td style="font-weight: bold;">Afmeting</td> 
        <td style="width: 120px; font-weight: bold;">Offerte</td> 
      </tr> 
      <tr> 
        <td>02502000</td> 
        <td>geschaafd 46x196</td> 
        <td>420 cm</td> 
        <td><a href="/offertes/?item=02502000|geschaafd 46x196|420 cm">vraag offerte aan</a></td> 
      </tr> 
      <tr> 
        <td><br />
           <br />
           <br />
           </td> 
        <td></td> 
        <td></td> 
        <td></td> 
      </tr> 
      <tr> 
        <td>02501500</td> 
        <td>geschaafd 46x146</td> 
        <td>270 cm</td> 
        <td><a href="/offertes/?item=02501500|geschaafd 46x146|270 cm">vraag offerte aan</a></td> 
      </tr> 
      <tr> 
        <td><br />
           <br />
           <br />
           </td> 
        <td></td> 
        <td></td> 
        <td></td> 
      </tr> 
    </tbody> 
  </table> </div>
```

I searched for al lot of things i can do. But because i can't use js in this CMS, it is pretty difficult to use some code.
The only thing i can use in my CMS is HTML.

Can someone plz help me out of this problem.

Comment: can you write inline javascript in there?

Comment: Are-you using pure javascript or JQuery?

Comment: Manipulating an HTML page dynamically without the use of Javascript or JQuery is close to impossible.

Comment: @reptildarat I can't use inline js in it

Comment: Well, i think maybe you can change your approach to use wizard like form, so user need to click a button to post his request manually to the server and server will return new html that contains your another drop down. and meanwhile you can save the user's input.

Comment: then there is no solution, aside from hacking together a flash object but what klutch that would be. can you change the code that runs the CMS?

Comment: @reptildarat Ok i will try that. I hope it will work.

Comment: @M.Scherzer no i can't change it. This cms is from a company. I only can change the inside html

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quiet simple or «complicated». Since you can't use JavaScript in your CMS, which is a standard. You will put your `<select>` tag in a `<form>` with a submit button... Then handle it on the server side.

I'm just curious a lot, which CMS are you talking about?

Comment: I am talking about MaxiCMS

Comment: Please can you provide me a link for documentation (French or English)